# overflow-y scroll always show even it not overflow

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm doing "Scroll JQuery Mobile Panel Separately From Content" ,[what I have done](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/scroll-inside-panel)

I apply this css to Achieve what I do but the problem is

overflow-y : scroll ==> Always show even its content not overflow.

Do you have any idea about it, Thank in advance.

```
.ui-panel-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try using `overflow: auto` instead. That will only show scrollbars when the content overflows the normal height, whereas `overflow: scroll` will show them all the time.

Comment: Even that didn't help me! Is there any other reason why this could be happening?

Comment: Omg dude... 10 minutes on this one Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**overflow-y : scroll** always display scroll bars, use **auto** instead.

```
.fixed-panel {
  min-height: 280px;
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```