# Large image stretches my div container horizontally

Tags: css

I have an application which allows you to drag an image into a div. The problem is that if the image is really large then it stretches the div horizontally and no scrollbar appears. My Div doesn't have a static width set because I'm using a grid type layoutv using percentages.  Is there anything I can do with the CSS for a scrollbar appears if the image overflows the div?

Comment: You could keep your grid percentages but apply a `max-width` to prevent the `<div>` from expanding past a pre-determined size.

Comment: what do you mean by static width and percentages?? is the overflow:scroll  not solving your problem?

Comment: I meant that the width is not something like 150px or 100px. It is 100% the parent. The parent is a percentage column. Has a width of 40%.  overflow:scroll will always show a scrollbar even when the is nothing larger than the container. Perhaps I need some JS to make this work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347165/overflow-y-scroll-always-show-even-it-not-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Set the CSS property `overflow: scroll;` on the div tag.

Comment: He said no width specified.